# setting comments off as default for pages and custom post types?

Tags: comments

I want to turn the comments off by default with pages and custom post-types

Initially I simply used conditionals in the comments display function to avoid displaying the block on these pages, but I need the user to be able to turn the comments back on as required.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder i've added an answer to this question that i believe has the desired effect..

Comment: I'm sure your function works well, but I had already selected an answer that works for my purpose.

Comment: Note: [Related Trac Ticket #12991](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12991)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to set pages and some custom post types to have commenting 'off' by default, while posts will still use the default option (i.e. commenting 'on'). If this is the case, the following function will do it.

```
function default_comments_off( $data ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' && $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' ) {
        $data['comment_status'] = 0;
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off' );
```

Comment: this fails when you wish to turn the comments back on. It needs to be edited to that it will run only once

Comment: not at a machine right now, but I guess you can use the metadata mechanic to check for meta, if there not run the function, else add the meta and run the function.

Comment: tested, this isn't going to work as simply as that because the post ID is not contained in the $data var in your function.

Comment: I tested it (with WP 3.0) before submitting my answer and it worked. What issue are you encountering? The post ID is not in $data because the post has not been created yet before the function is run (look at the filter in function wp_insert_post). The function will run only when you visit wp-admin/post-new.php?post-type=xxx, before you enter any content in the fields.

Comment: on my test server, I can not turn comments back on, they are perpetually set to off.

Comment: How do you test it? I cannot reproduce the issue. This is what I am doing: "create a new page (comments are off by default) -> save the page -> turn comments on -> save", "create a new page -> turn comments on -> save". And everything worked as expected.

Comment: I see, this only functions after you have placed content in. I suppose this a bug that is very easy to live with.

Comment: sorich, what does the && $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' part of that function do? It seems like that would turn comments off only for auto-draft posts (or pages, in this case). Is that correct?

Comment: Correct @tnorthcutt.

Answer (score 12):

When you create a new post(custom type or regular), WordPress calls `get_default_post_to_edit` which then sets the default values a new post will have.

This function provides a few filter hooks for changing the default title, content and excerpt, but unfortunately nothing else... however each filter passes along the complete `$post` object to the callback, essentially this means it's possible to redefine several properties(or just one if we like)

This should work for you, simply add the post types the code should apply to as cases inside the switch.. (movie and page are examples)..

```
function my_default_content( $post_content, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type )
    switch( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'page':
        case 'movie':
            $post->comment_status = 'closed';
        break;
    }
    return $post_content;
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_default_content', 10, 2 );
```

Code was tested on WP 3.0.1 and has the desired effect of disabling comments for the post types specifically whilst leaving others to inherit **default** status from the `default_comment_status` option.

Hope that helps.... :)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a plugin to disable comments on pages by default.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-comments-off-please/

Perhaps that will help?

Comment: seems excessive given the 5 line solution in sorich87's answer! Cheers though.

Comment: Not really, there's many approaches to tackling code requirements, it's just a different method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend still using your conditionals in the comments display, but use options to store your conditional settings.  Then you can add a page to the Settings menu that allows administrators to turn comments on or off as needed.

---

#### Update

It occurs to me that you want to set the default for commenting to "off" as a global setting rather than setting it to "off" each time you create a page.  This **is** possible.

Go to Settings >> Discussion in the WordPress admin section.  In the first section ("Default Article Settings" you'll see an option called "Allow people to post comments on new articles" ... uncheck this option.

Now, by default, comments will be turned "off" for all new posts, pages, and custom post types.  You can still turn comments back "on" on a case-by-case basis by selecting the appropriate checkbox in the "Discussion" meta box on the individual post/page edit screen.

Comment: There is already an option there, though. I simply want it off by default.

Comment: There is already an option where?  Are you referring to the "Discussion" box at the bottom of the post/page edit screen?

Comment: Yes, I just want that to be unchecked. Sorich87 solution almost works. Not at a machine to try anything out yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/turn-off-comments-on-pages-by-default), what you're requesting isn't possible without the use of a custom plugin or function to accomplish it.

Comment: I have no problem writing one, just need to be pointed in the right direction. Hooks & filters etc that may help.

Comment: If you do end up writing one, please share what you did here! Seems like a plugin that can do that would get a lot of use.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more elegant way to do this in 2022:

```
function disable_comments_on_attachments_by_default( $status, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'attachment' ) {
        $status = 'closed';
    }

    return $status;
}

add_filter( 'get_default_comment_status', 'disable_comments_on_attachments_by_default', 10, 2 );
```

That disables all comment types (comments and pingbacks/trackbacks) on new media library attachments. You can obviously change the post type to whatever you want, or you can include the third parameter in the `get_default_comment_status` filter to affect only a specific comment type.

Answer (score -2):

If you simply add this code in functions.php

```
<?php
add_post_type_support( 'your_custom_post_type', array( 'comments' ) );
?>
```

Go to the post, and in the screen options, tick on "Discussion" and "Comments", you can enable/disable comments for each custom post type.

Comment: doesn't really answer the (albeit already answered) question