# Forcing all posts associated with a custom post type to be private

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, password

Does anyone know of a way to add code to the functions.php file which will automatically force all posts belonging to a custom post type to be "private" and/or "password protected" with a default password set?

I am specifically referring to creating a new post or editing an existing post thus ensuring a post belonging to a specific custom post type never changes...

Comment: Do you want to prevent editing, but allow public viewing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook onto `save_post`, `wp_insert_post` or `wp_insert_post_data` to modify the post object prior to it being inserted or saved.

Using `save_post` or `wp_insert_post` the callback would need to declare two args and would receive the post object as the second incoming variable.. (and i'm showing you to cover the alternatives, TheDeadMedic's example would be fine to).

For setting default values for a particular post type for **new** posts you can use a small hack by hooking onto `default_content` (although `default_title` would also work to), like the example i gave [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/setting-comments-off-as-default-for-pages-and-custom-post-types/3828#3828).

You essentially need two functions, one to modify post objects at the time of save/insert and one to set default post object values, here's an example of the two necessary functions(again noting you can swap my save_post callback for the example already given by TheDeadMedic).

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'check_type_values', 10, 2 );

function check_type_values( $post_id, $post ) {

    if( $post->post_type )
        switch( $post->post_type ) {
            case 'my_custom_type':
                $post->post_status = 'private';
                $post->post_password = ( '' == $post->post_password ) ? 'some_default_when_no_password' : $post->post_password;
            break;
        }   
    return;
}

add_filter( 'default_content', 'set_default_values', 10, 2 );

function set_default_values( $post_content, $post ) {

    if( $post->post_type )
        switch( $post->post_type ) {
            case 'my_custom_type':
                $post->post_status = 'private';
                $post->post_password = 'some_default_password';
            break;
        }
    return $post_content;
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Nice one for going the extra mile :) Although I would advise using `wp_insert_post_data` over `wp_insert_post` (the latter merely gets fired once the post is saved, and you'd need to invoke a save again if you wanted to change data, whilst the former allows you to *change* the post data, *before* it's saved to the database).

Comment: Good point, my answer was mainly intended to compliment your own... just wanted to make sure the "setting default values" aspect was covered(noone noticed my answer in the other topic), and figured i might aswell show how to use one of the other hooks whilst i'm at it.. :)

Comment: @TheDealMedic and @t31os -- quick question on this. Based on the Medics comment, where would "wp_insert_post" or "wp_insert_post_data" be used within the code? Would you mind modifying the answer with the correct code so that its easily usable by others?

Comment: @TheDealMedic and @t31os -- Also, in testing this code further I noticed that if an existing post (which is not private) is edited through the backend and then subsequently saved the post status does not change to "private". Although I can see situations where only new posts get a default value of "private" for my current situation I would like to enforce that all posts for this post type are "private" and where this option can not be modified by any users other than the administrator. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Ok, well simply follow TDM's advice and use the `wp_insert_post_data` hook. Note, any approach isn't going to automatically fix any posts created already that do not have their status set to private, you'll need something seperate to run over existing posts and adjust the post status..

Answer (score 4):

```
function force_type_private($post)
{
    if ($post['post_type'] != 'my_post_type' || $post['post_status'] == 'trash')
        return $post;

    $post['post_password'] = 'my password';
    $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    return $post;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```

Comment: I wouldn't add the `$post['post_password']` section.  There's a significant different between private posts and password-protected posts.

Comment: @EAMann It was mainly for demonstrative purposes, but I guess I should have mentioned that :)

Comment: @EAmann -- EAMann, I consider you to be a true expert in this community and I am curious to hear your feedback on each of the proposed solutions (if anyone else has feedback please also comment)... What do you feel is the best approach. I ask because this answer seems simple and clean and has 3 votes where as the previous answer I accepted has only two votes and seems more complex but possibly comprehensive for different situations. Let's assume we are just focusing on setting all posts to "private" and eliminate the password protected option.

Comment: @TheDealMedic or @EAMann -- Also, in testing your code further it does seem that your solution seems to be a better alternative to the previous one I accepted so I accepted this answer as the correct one. Could you extend your code to show how the option to modify the "visibility" can be removed and also hopefully show how the visibility can be edited/changed if the user logged in is an admin or has that capability?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't we just make a template page for the custom post type and do a check if the is the user is logged in and check if the user is a certain role? Lets take for example you want to have a post-type that is only to be viewed by the admins:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() ) : if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; endif; ?>
```

Comment: davis, you are mis-reading the Question, this is about the backend (`/wp-admin/`)...

Answer (score 0):

There are three hooks specifically for when the status of a post changes:

```
/**
 * Fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.
 */
do_action( 'transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post );

/**
 * Fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.
 *
 * The dynamic portions of the hook name, `$new_status` and `$old_status`,
 * refer to the old and new post statuses, respectively.
 */
do_action( "{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $post );

/**
 * Fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another.
 *
 * The dynamic portions of the hook name, `$new_status` and `$post->post_type`,
 * refer to the new post status and post type, respectively.
 */
do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );
```

How to use:

```
/**
 * Portfolio always published as private
 *
 * @param $post_id
 */
function wp_neavr2_portfolio_always_publish_as_private( $post_id ) {

    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'          => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'private',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'publish_portfolio', 'wp_neavr2_portfolio_always_publish_as_private' );
```

In this case, the `portfolio` post type will always be published privately. However, it is possible to create a draft, as this is not restricted.

Note that since this is not a filter, you must use the `wp_update_post()` function to update the status.