# Automatically set default password to all posts in a specific category

Tags: categories, filters, password

Let's say that we have a category with slug `protected_category` and some posts in it.
Is there a way to force all posts in that category to be password protected using a default password?

**UPDATE:** I found a solution how to set a default password to all posts in a custom post type:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'set_default_values', 10, 2 );
function set_default_values( $post_content, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type )
        switch ( $post->post_type ) {
            case 'protected_post':
                $post->post_status = 'protected';
                $post->post_password = '123123';
                break;
        }

    return $post_content; 
}
```

So how can I modify this to target a specific category?

Comment: You've not given information about your setup, but generally this is possible. Please extend your question with sufficient information, what's your approach, what've you tried so far? Besides that, take a look at [Forcing all posts associated with a custom post type to be private](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4952/22534), which is of course is about making a specific post type private, but the methods can be adopted for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
add_filter('save_post', 'wpse_135377_protect_post');
function wpse_135377_protect_post($post_ID) {
    if (in_array(
        'protected_category',
        wp_get_post_categories($post_ID, array('fields' => 'slugs'))
    )) {
        // we have to remove the function
        // as it will be called by `wp_update_post` (=> infinite loop)
        remove_filter('save_post', 'wpse_135377_protect_post');
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_ID,
            'post_password' => '123123',
        ));
        // now we add it again
        add_filter('save_post', 'wpse_135377_protect_post');
    }
} // function wpse_135377_protect_post
```

There were several problems in your code base:

- there is no post status `protected`—password protected posts have the post status `publish` as well (and they have a password);
- you should use the `save_post` action (as suggested in the below comment and the linked answer);
- the `$post` object that is passed into the functions (`save_post` as well as `default_content`) is **not** a pointer (reference) so anything you do to the object stays within the function (unless you insert it into the db).

Happy protecting!

Comment: It doesn't work :(...Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: I've tried the last but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could help me :(

Comment: maybe you should try `save_post` hook instead

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...Thank you @t f; with very little modifications to suite my theme now works like a charm :)