# "Discussion" checkboxes unchecked by default on pages?

Tags: comments, metabox, dashboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting comments off as default for pages and custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/setting-comments-off-as-default-for-pages-and-custom-post-types)

When I create a new page, I want these two checkboxes (from the "Discussion" meta box) to appear unchecked by default.

Can this be done programmatically?

[image: "Discussion" meta box]

Comment: I'm assuming you already figured that turning off comments on the setting page won't work for your case?

Comment: No. They should appear unchecked for the "page" post type only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-register the "page" post type and leave out the comments capability.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_page_type' );

function my_new_page_type() {
    register_post_type( 'page', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Page', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        '_builtin' => true, /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', /* internal use only. don't use this when registering your own post type. */
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'query_var' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
    ) );
}
```

#### Actual answer: [original source here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/setting-comments-off-as-default-for-pages-and-custom-post-types/2082#2082)

```
function default_comments_off( $data ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' && $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' ) {
        $data['comment_status'] = 0;
        $data['ping_status'] = 0;
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off' );
```

Comment: You'll still probably want to manually deactivate comments for all existing pages first.

Comment: Didn't try it yet, but won't that completely disable the ability to comment?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the goal, but now I see that you simply just want it to default off with the option to turn them on. Not sure about that one yet.

Comment: Here we go: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2082/3293

Comment: That solution seems to work, thanks! You should update your answer or vote to close this Q as dupe

Comment: That's not the answer...

Comment: Added code to this answer as first snippet within answer is incorrect, however @developdaly links to the correct answer in the comments above me **which may be missed at a glance**. I added `$data['ping_status'] = 0;` which was absent from the code to also uncheck the trackbacks as per OP request. Also [this answer within the thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67582/13418) by *Dankicity* also works, albeit expressed differently. Where as the one by *Chrisguitarguy* turns off comments entirely (no more checkboxes available).

Answer (score 4):

Re-registering the `page` post type is a bit excessive.  `remove_post_type_support` is a bit easier.  Combined with the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2082/3293) mentioned by @developdaly, and you'll effectively turn comments off.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse48145_remove_comments', 99 );
/**
 * Removes support for comments from Pages.
 * 
 * @uses remove_post_type_support
 */
function wpse48145_remove_comments()
{
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the 'correct answer' - a lot neater.

Comment: @StephenHarris No one read the question! :D (And I even upvoted them!).

Comment: I fairly certain the question changed since I posted this answer?

Answer (score 3):

This has/had annoyed me for a while so I did *some* digging around:

```
function wpse48145_unchecked_page_discussion () {
      if( 'page' == $_REQUEST[ 'post_type' ]  ) {
        add_filter( 'pre_option_default_comment_status', 'wpse48145_unchecked_page_discussion_filter' );
        // & if you want...
        add_filter( 'pre_option_default_ping_status', 'wpse48145_unchecked_page_discussion_filter' );
    }
}
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse48145_unchecked_page_discussion' );

function wpse48145_unchecked_page_discussion_filter ( $val ) {
    return 'closed';
}
```

works as of WP 3.4.2

Comment: +1 But please use `get_post_type()` instead of `$_REQUEST['post_type']`. Also: You don't have to state the priority and var number on `add_filter/*_action` calls when it's only one argument.

Comment: `get_post_type()` is not available by that time.  I just followed the methodology in wp-admin/admin.php where the load-{page} action is triggered.

Comment: `$_POST` doesn't work there, only `$_REQUEST` or more appropriately, `$_GET`. Tried to test `get_post_type` even with passing globals and no dice.. looks like `$_REQUEST/$_GET` is the only way...

Comment: I now added the solution to the trac ticket, that @ChipBennet posted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **`Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion`**
2. Find **Default Article settings**
3. Uncheck "*Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)*" and "*Allow people to post comments on new articles*"

These changes *will not* change settings for existing posts. If you want to change existing posts, do a **Bulk Edit** from the **`Dashboard -> Posts`** screen.

#### Edit

Sorry, I misread your question initially. WordPress doesn't provide a UI to set default comment status based on post type.

Note: [this is a known issue](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12991).

Comment: This also affects posts. I only need it for pages

Comment: Sorry; misread your post. See update, and linked Trac bug report.